# How can I screen share into a remote coworker's Mac?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I have a coworker who should do some testing on a Mac but is a Windows user who has no desire to learn the Mac. If I could just log in to his Mac, which is on a wireless network, and do his work for him I would be so much better off. I am about 2000 miles away from him, however and we are not on the same network (it's a small company).

So...is it possible to remotely take over his computer by enabling remote administration in Settings, without being on the same network?

Answer (score 1):

There is a long list of options, I'll just mention a few

- you can both set up an iChat account and use screen sharing there
- both parties can install (and log in to) Skype which provides screen sharing as well
- install [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) on both machines

In your situation I would probably go with the TeamViewer option.

Comment: Yeah, he keeps saying that Skype doesn't support screen sharing and then he literally ignores my requests to upgrade to the latest Skype.
 As for Team Viewer, even if it's free I'd be very concerned about who made it... if it were open source then OK. If not, why not assume it's spyware?

Comment: Uhh, good luck then with having him install TeamViewer and sending you the login details. Isn't there anybody else on site who can at least support in these basic steps? TeamViewer is not open source so there is a certain risk (but this applies to iChat and Skype as well). But given your coworker's level of collaboration I wouldn't recommend any more complex solutions. How confidential is your work?

Comment: I finally got him to accept upgrading Skype. But that was after wasting an entire day because he miscommunicated something that would have been crystal clear with a screen share.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Logmein Free](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/). I would highly recommend this because you don't need to have iChat or Skype open. Logmein shows up as a little menulet in your menu bar:
[image: Logmein menulet]

For security, you need to have both the username and password of the Mac you are connecting to, *and,* if you specify, a personal password.
[image: Logmein welcome screen]

It will also alert you if anyone is connected to your computer:

[image: Alert screen]

Comment: There seem to be many such programs these days, all produced by unknown parties who could easily be linked to organized crime or security services, you'd never know without a ton of investigation.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Logmein can be trusted. Go look up a review of Logmein.